How can I secure the corner of a click-lock vinyl tile?
Installed some click lock vinyl tiles in our bathroom and noticed one corner is now squishy/moving up and down slightly. I am wondering what would be the best way to secure it to the floor so it doesn’t move.
See below photo of the junction that seems a little loose.


More likely the sub floor is not flat enough for that flooring.  Best would be to take up the flooring and check/fix the sub floor.  Nails/glue might only fix it for a short time.

Pinning an otherwise floating floor in one spot with nails is not a great plan.

Is the tile separating at the layer junction, or is the entire tile thickness moving?

If you laid the tile recently give it some time to conform to the subfloor. After a few weeks it can relax into the space and the "squishy" feeling will be gone.
DO NOT try to nail it. The nails can crack the solid core and really ruin the tile. Try being patient first.

Maybe use some gentle heat to help it conform too.

Heat will not soften the solid core, but could soften the vinyl surface.  I would not recommend heat be applied.
